# Uncaught TypeError: _projects_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default is undefined

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-router

I am trying to extract params from the url and react accordingly. All the extraction works fine but after modifying my code to import my router and trying to push a route, I've run into an error I simply don't understand.

```
Uncaught TypeError: _projects_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default is undefined
    <anonymous> index.js:18
    js projects.js:99
    __webpack_require__ projects.js:241
    fn projects.js:470
    <anonymous> projects.js:6
    js projects.js:89
    __webpack_require__ projects.js:241
    fn projects.js:470
    <anonymous> index.js:2
    node_modules index.js:19
    __webpack_require__ projects.js:241
    fn projects.js:470
    <anonymous> FiltersComp.vue:5
    js projects.js:149
    __webpack_require__ projects.js:241
    fn projects.js:470
    <anonymous> FiltersComp.vue:3
    vue projects.js:119
    __webpack_require__ projects.js:241
    fn projects.js:470
    <anonymous> index.js:3
    node_modules index.js:29
    __webpack_require__ projects.js:241
    fn projects.js:470
    <anonymous> App.vue:5
    js projects.js:159
    __webpack_require__ projects.js:241
    fn projects.js:470
    <anonymous> App.vue:3
    vue projects.js:129
    __webpack_require__ projects.js:241
    fn projects.js:470
    <anonymous> main.js:3
    js projects.js:79
    __webpack_require__ projects.js:241
    __webpack_exports__ projects.js:1357
    O projects.js:283
    <anonymous> projects.js:1358
    <anonymous> projects.js:1360
```

Here is my /routes/index.js:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import ProjectsSub from "../views/ProjectsSub.vue";
import Tr from "../../../../translation.js";
import Pr from "../projects.js"


const routes = [
  {
    path: "/projects",
    name: "projects",
    component: ProjectsSub,
  },
  {
    path: "/projects/:filter",
    name: "filtered",
    component: ProjectsSub,
    beforeEnter: Pr.routeMiddleware
  }
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, _from, next) => {
  const userLocale = Tr.chooseDefaultLocale();
  Tr.switchLanguage(userLocale);
  next();
});

export default router;
```

Here's my projects.js:

```
import Tr from './../../../translation.js'
const languages = Tr.languages
import store from './store';
import router from './routes';

const Projects = {

  filterOptions: { /*filters which I removed because not relevant for this question*/ },

  getFiltersFromUrl(url) {
    const urlParams = url.split('&');
    const conditions = {};
    let currentField = null;
    let conditionValues = [];
    let reformatingRequired = false

    urlParams.forEach(param => {
        const [key, value] = param.split('=');
        if (key.startsWith('field')) {
            if (currentField !== null) {
                conditions[currentField] = conditionValues;
                conditionValues = []; 
            }
            currentField = decodeURIComponent(value);
        } else if (key.startsWith('condition')) {
            const conditionValue = decodeURIComponent(value);
            conditionValues.push(conditionValue);
        } else {
          reformatingRequired = true
        }
    });

    if (currentField !== null) {
        conditions[currentField] = conditionValues;
    }

    const sortedFilters = {};
    Object.entries(conditions).forEach(([field, condition]) => {
        sortedFilters[field] = condition;
    });

    return { sortedFilters, reformatingRequired }
  },

  async isFilterSupported(params) {
    const filtersFromUrl = Projects.getFiltersFromUrl(params)
    const appliedFilters = filtersFromUrl.sortedFilters;
    const existingFilters = { 'lang': [], 'status': [], 'tags': [] }
    let exists = false
    for (const field in appliedFilters) {
      if ((field in Projects.filterOptions)){
        for (const filter in appliedFilters[field]) {
          for (const option in Projects.filterOptions[field]['options']) {
            const value = Projects.filterOptions[field]['options'][option]['value']
            if ((appliedFilters[field][filter] == value) && (value != 'all')) {
              exists = true
              existingFilters[field].push(appliedFilters[field][filter])
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (!exists) {
      console.log('emergency')
      try {
        await router.push("/projects")
      } catch(e) {
        console.log('&', e)
        router.replace({ params: { filter: '' } })
      }
    } else if (filtersFromUrl.reformatingRequired) {
      Projects.buildUrl(existingFilters)
    } else {
      console.log('b', appliedFilters, exists, existingFilters)
    }
  },

  buildUrl(filters) {
    console.log('a', filters)
  },

  async routeMiddleware(to, _from, next) {
    const paramFilters = to.params.filter
    Projects.isFilterSupported(paramFilters)
    return next()
  },
}
export default Projects
```

I think that I might just need to call router.push() in another file than the one which is called at beforeEnter. If that's the case could you explain me the reasoning why I can't just import router in projects.js and how I need to call router.push()?

Comment: I think you may have a circular import. In routes/index.js you are importing projects.js, which is importing router from routes/index.js that has not been defined yet. You need to refactor your code. For example routeMiddleware is more appropriate to be defined in routes. Also, it is difficult to tell what is the purpose of Projects object. I would recommend to divide it into bits with a more defined logic.